# CImg library not loading image

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, cimg

I have followed the CImg [tutorial](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html) and I it works perfectly. However, if I try to load a different image (other than lena.jpg), I get a stack overflow error.

For example, this works:

```
CImg<float> image;
string filePath = "C:/Users/zzz/Documents/lena.jpg";
image.load(filePath.c_str());
```

But this gives an error:

```
CImg<float> image;
string filePath = "C:/Users/zzz/Documents/anotherimage.jpg";
image.load(filePath.c_str());
```

The error is:
Unhandled exception at 0x77bb15de in LoadImageTest.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.

I thought the stack overflow was due to "anotherimage.jpg" being too large, so I also tried a really small image (16x16 pixels). This resulted in the same error.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CImg<float> image;

    // This works...
    string filePath = "C:/Users/zzz/Pictures/lena.jpg";

    // This doesn't work...
    // string filePath = "C:/Users/zzz/Pictures/small.jpg";

    image.load(filePath.c_str());

    CImgDisplay main_disp(image, "The image");

    while (!main_disp.is_closed())
    {
        main_disp.wait();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's that part that gives the error? Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: Have you tried `"C:\\Users\\zzz\\Documents\\lena.jpg"`?

Comment: We need more code. We like code.

Comment: Stepping through the code in the debugger shows that it's the image.load() line causing the error.

Comment: @Nick, Windows responds to both forms of directory separator character, `\\ ` or `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks weird. Are you sure this is indeed a file in JPG format ? Does it use some special JPEG formats (B&W, 12 bits ?, ...).

Comment: Thanks that solved it! Looking at the image properties, lena.jpg was actually a bitmap (weird), whereas the other images were genuine jpegs. I installed ImageMagick and it worked fine.